# Sendgrid on Heroku with apikey authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, sendgrid

I have a rails app on Heroku which was sending emails through Sendgrid smtp relay mechanism using basic (username/ password) authentication. I changed it to use api key but the email messages are showing in Deferred status on Sendgrid Activity screen since then. Does that mean the api key access worked? How can I resolve this? I have the apikey configured in my rails environment variables as well as on the Sendgrid add-on in Heroku.

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/deferrals/

Comment: Please check it - [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings`? I ran into a similar (although not identical) situation given that it seems like recently Sendgrid changed the way in which credentials are provided for SMTP delivery. In my case, in addition to adding an `ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']` to Heroku, I also had to update from:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

to

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'apikey', # <---- Changed
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],  # <---- Changed
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```